# How to apply multiple labels to jenkins nodes?

Tags: jenkins

When I apply a label to Node, it is working as expected and the job able to pick this node.

But, if I apply multiple labels, it is not working.
As I observe, it is taking both of them as single label.

Example:
label: devbuild

It is working with the job.

But,

label: devbuild,installernode

It is not working for any of the jobs with label "devbuild" or "installernode"
Even I tried with ; but same issue.

Please suggest how to apply multiple labels to single node.

Comment: It's space separated. [Label conditions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) can also be used. For example: `agent { label 'my-label1 && my-label2' }` or `agent { label 'my-label1 || my-label2' }`. That would be on the job side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Jenkins instance, node labels are separated by spaces (not commas nor semicolons).  So:

```
devbuild installernode
```

Should work for you.

Comment: Yeah observed that, thank you.